# Does Photoshop "Save for web" still resample if you don't resize?

Tags: adobe, photoshop, image-resizing, resampling

Will resampling still happen if you don't resize your image in Photoshop on save for web?

I understand resizing vs resampling is making print size smaller with same pixels vs. less pixels with interpolation. But what if I'm saving for web, but not wanting to do either? Will it still resample?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Save for web didn't resample your image. The quality and the definition are exactly the same than the orginal.
BUT, "Save for the web" change a CMYN, 300 dpi image in a RGB,72 dpi image without resample anything.